# Maintaining a persistent connection during video upload

Tags: python, youtube, amazon-s3

I have a Flash video upload that is going from the browser directly to S3. It works.

However, if the connection is interrupted, it will time out after about three seconds. On the other hand, if you upload a video to YouTube, even if you disconnect the internet, it will hang and then resume when the internet connection is working again. To test this, I uploaded a video, stopped my connection for five minutes (timed), and then started my internet connection again. After about thirty seconds the video continued uploading again. This is especially important, since the videos being uploaded are quite large (1GB+) and it may take several hours to upload.

How does YouTube do this? What do I need to change or examine in my own uploader in order for it to work as YouTube's does?